# WebClient baixa uma string errada

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-basic-6, ftp

Estou tentando criar um sistema de inteligência virtual, e hospedei os arquivos da linguagem no meu FTP. Esses arquivos são de uma linguagem que eu mesmo fiz, chamado SVDB, e hospedei no FTP, e quando vou baixar no aplicativo o arquivo de textos ele vem com HTML. Esse é o arquivo original (hospedado no FTP):

```
default {
   wrong: "Desculpe, não entendi";
   language-name: "Português Brasileiro";
   language-code: "PT-BR";
   version: "1.0";
}
replace-strings {
   R0001: "vc|você";
   R0002: "td|tudo";
}
K00001 {
   input: "olá|ola|oi|eae";
   output: "Olá!";
   action-id: "";
}
K00002 {
   input: "tudo bem?|você está bem?";
   output: "Estou bem, obrigado por perguntar.";
   action-id: "";
}
```

E é isso o que o `WebClient.DownloadString()` baixa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele baixa um código totalmente nada a ver com o que eu quero, e o Parser do SVDB da erro. Esse é o endereço onde está hospedado o arquivo:

> http://server-advenker32.66ghz.com/Panthon/Server/Langs/pt-br/input.txt

E esse é o código que estou usando para baixar o arquivo:

```
Public Function GetLanguageServer(ByVal LangCode As String) As MainServer
    Dim v As New WebClient
    Dim s As String = v.DownloadString("http://server-advenker32.66ghz.com/Panthon/Server/Langs/" & LangCode.ToLower & "/input.txt")
    Return TextParser.ResolveServerFromString(s) ' o Parser tenta entender o que foi baixado aqui
End Function
```

Então, como eu baixo o arquivo de uma formatação como a original mostrada ali em cima?

> **Nota:** As permissões do arquivo hospedado estão com o código 744 (Permissões públicas de leitura)
>
> **Nota:** O arquivo é hospedado no meu FTP da empresa uHostAll.
>
> **Nota:** Ao tentar acessar o arquivo pelo navegador, aparece corretamente e sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Então, como eu emulo isso? Eu tava pensando em poder selecionar o texto do componente `WebBrowser` e copiar, por que nele aparece certinho, mas não sei como poderia fazer isso, e o pior é que a propriedade `DocumentText` não retorna nada...

Comment: De qual API você está falando, do SVDB?

Comment: Tem alguma coisa no meio do arquivo servindo esse "filtro de conteudo". Não tem como fazer um acesso direto? Seu arquivo está sendo servido por alguma coisa intermediária. Uma hospedagem normal nao faz isso.

Comment: Bom, uma hospedagem que coloca um JS no meio do caminho pra mim está longe de ser apropriada. Ou tem algo que você não quer comentar, ou está usando indevidamente algum recurso dela que tem cara de gambiarra  :) - Se o problema é burlar essa hospedagem, a pergunta seria outra. Da forma que está, o problema é a hospedagem, e não o seu código e nem a sua API.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, então consegui burlar minha própria hospedagem com essa resposta que fiz agora >:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui por um outro método, eu criei um WebBrowser e simplesmente naveguei para o link do arquivo, este é o método agora:

```
Public Sub GetLanguageServer(ByVal LangCode As String)
    Dim address As String = "http://server-advenker32.66ghz.com/Panthon/Server/Langs/pt-br/input.txt"
    Dim BrowserClient As New WebBrowser
    BrowserClient.Navigate(address)
    AddHandler BrowserClient.DocumentCompleted, Sub() SDK = TextParser.ResolveServerFromString(BrowserClient.Document.Body.InnerText)
End Sub
```

E funcionou, a propriedade `Document.Body.InnerText` retornou o arquivo.

Comment: Acho melhor já excluir a pergunta kkk

Comment: Não posso remover uma pergunta com recompensa ;-;

Comment: E não pode dar ela pra vc mesmo kkk. Deixe como está, ponha só um aviso na resposta, dizendo que seu código original estava certo, mas a hospedagem tem um filtro de conteúdo, entao vc contornou com o WebBrowser. Jajá vou apagando meus comments. O melhor é que se vc explicar isso na resposta, ao menos dá pra dar +1 nela :D

Comment: Tudo bem, vou explicar xD

Comment: Se quiser tomar por base, o que acontece é mais ou menos o seguinte: Ao acessar o arquivo, há uma verificação no servidor por um determinado cookie. Caso ele não esteja setado, em vez do arquivo original ser servido, é enviada uma página com JS para o cliente que seta este cookie usando alguns _hashes_, e em seguida redirecionando o cliente para o mesmo endereço, acrescido de uma _query string_. Estando com os cookies corretos, o arquivo original é finalmente servido. Como o WebBrowser já faz toda esta operação por você, como se estivesse navegando, sua solução foi pegar só o resultado final.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

tudo bem?

Fazendo com WebBrowser você irá consumir mais recursos que um webclient, pois o mesmo é um wrapper do IE e com isto irá executar toda a pilha de processamento e renderização do internet explorer.
Para fazer o que você pediu, basta fazer.

```
        //Exemplo gravando em um arquivo físico
        using (var client = new WebClient())
            client.DownloadFile("http://namitec.com.br/teste.txt", @"c:\temp\teste.txt");

        //Exemplo lendo direto para memória
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://namitec.com.br/teste.txt")))
            {
                var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
```

Tomei a liberdade de colocar o exemplo neste endereço para que você possa testar.

Comment: Isto não funcionaria no caso do que foi perguntado, pois dependia de cookies setados por JS.